# How to use Django streaming download a file when writting data to it?

Tags: python, django

How to use Django to streaming download a file when writing data to it?

That means I don't know the file size when I start downloading it.

Comment: Hello, have you read this page, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects - StreamingHttpResponse section

Comment: @404pio Yes, I have read it and know I can't use write method. Is it possible in other solutions?

Comment: there is also example, look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-csv-files - the most important element of example if a kind of buffer `Echo`, and brackets around forloop